# Python3 not accessing requests module

Tags: python, import, path, cmd, python-requests

I've installed the requests module for Python3 on my system, and appears to have installed completely fine. When I run a script involving use of said package on PyCham using Python3 interpreter, it runs without a problem. However, when executed outside this environment, this error pops up:

```
ImportError: no module named requests
```

This happens despite `PATH` containing Python34, which invokes correctly when call via `cmd`, and me double checking the installation via `pip`. Is there any possible area you could point me to that could resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have two Pythons installed. One is used by PyCharm (and it has `requests`) and second is used in `cmd`. Beside `pip` can be part of Python used by PyCharm not Python used in `cmd`.

Comment: Perhaps. I do have Python2 and 3; however both `cmd` and PyCham use version 3. I think the problem may be that the version executing when I invoke the `.py` files directly is Python2. I'm gonna quickly test this, watch this space.

Comment: The above is true. What is the variable/setting that could switch it to 3?

Comment: It seems you use Windows (`cmd`) and Windows has this setting in register. Try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859/en-us - it is description for Windows XP but it should work in Windows 7. I don't use Windows for 2-3 years so I don't know how to do this in Windows 8.